# codeigniter database where_in error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am getting confused. I am trying below query:

```
$this->db->select('id')->from("orders")->where("status", "Active")->where_in($this->session->id, $this->db->query("SELECT `associated_staffs` FROM `orders` WHERE `status`='Active'")->result());
$total_rows = $this->db->count_all_results();
```

It is generating below sql query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `numrows` FROM `orders` WHERE `status` = 'Active' AND 3 IN(, )
```

but it should generate:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `numrows` FROM `orders` WHERE `status` = 'Active' AND 3 IN(3,14,2 )
```

I am not getting anyway how to do it. Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like

```
    $this->db->where(array('active' => 1));
    $this->db->from('cars'); //table name here
    $this->db->where_in('id', array(1, 2, 3, 3)); //pass yoru where_in values here
    $cars = $this->db->count_all_results();
    echo $cars;
    echo $this->db->last_query();
```

output::

> SELECT COUNT(*) AS `numrows` FROM `cars` WHERE `active` = 1 AND `id` IN(1, 2, 3, 3)

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple method

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT id FROM orders WHERE status = 'Active' AND 3 IN(3,14,2)");
$result = $query->result_array();
return $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  $this->db->select('COUNT(*) AS numrows');
  $this->db->from('orders');
  $this->db->where_in(3,array(3,14,2));
  $this->db->where('status','Active');
  $query=$this->db->get();

  $result=$query->row();
  echo $result->numrows;
```